# How to set up run configuration on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm starting out learning how to code in Java and I'm trying to get the classic "Hello World" to run.
All tutorials I have seen online haven't shown how to set up the run configuration to do this or maybe I'm just missing something very simple.
Thanks in advance for helping!
Here the code I have so far:

```
public class FirstCode {
    public static void main(String args)
    {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try exploring anything on your own? I can find few links by simply searching "run configuration in eclipse".

Comment: I think if you do the steps here again, your problem will be solved. Maybe you missed one of the steps: https://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/how-to-create-build-and-run-a-java-hello-world-program-with-eclipse

Comment: Yep totally right! Just need go a few steps back. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps to configure the settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]